# How can I get a list of all mp3 files on the sd card regardless of directory in android?

Tags: android, file

Using code from open source MusicDroid with the following code that I found during a search for this problem, I can only get mp3 files that are in the root directory /sdcard/

```
File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
    for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) {
        songs.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>
          (this,R.layout.song_item,songs);
    setListAdapter(songList);
}
```

How can I get all the mp3 files from the card (in any directory) into my 'songs' list?

Comment: You're going to have to recurse through each directory, listing the contained directories, and then listing the directories and mp3s inside each of the nested directories.

That is, you're probably not going to find a fancy api function for this. You'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you could just query the media store. Android scans the sdcard every time it is remounted, so MediaStore.Audio should have all the information you need.

Comment: OK, I can use MediaStore.Audio.DATA field and that gives me what I need.  Thanks.